# Can't Change Branches on Visual Studio Mac

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-mac

I have recently started a project on my Windows PC which I want to be able to take with my on my Mac. My friends and I are learning Git together.

I am having trouble finding where you change branches on macOS Visual Studio.

Pictured: 'Version Control' menu on macOS:

[image]

Am I missing something? Am I supposed to change branches elsewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the actions did you take? Have you cloned/created git repo?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I checkout'd the repo. And that is the menu I see once I have cone that.

Comment: What if you use `git status` command in your local repo?

Comment: IDK how to do that. I've heard the menu should have 'Version Control > Manage Branches and Remote' but as you can see I do not have that.

Comment: In the terminal window, `cd /path/to/the/local/git/repo` (a `.git` folder also exist there), and use the command `git status`.

Answer (score 7):

If your branch is newly created and you want to switch from previous branch to the new one you should click on `Version Control` -> `Manage Branches and Remotes` and come to the `Remote Sources`, select newly created branch and do the following. After that your branch will be visible in `Branches section`. Just select and click on `Switch to Branch`;

[image]

[image]

Comment: What should I do if pressing the "Track" button doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac I have the following as seen in this pic. From the "manage branches and repositories," you can create and switch to a different branch.

[image]